# Mysql query results from last 604800 seconds

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get my query results from last week.
The database uses UNIX Timestamp, so it's in seconds.

I've come up with this, but that doesn't seem to work. It gives me the all-time results. I just needs the results from the last 604.800 seconds.

```
    SELECT `mod_id`, COUNT(`mod_id`) m from `history_spottings` WHERE (`created` - 604800)
GROUP BY `mod_id`
ORDER BY m DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `mod_id`, COUNT(`mod_id`) m from `history_spottings` WHERE `created` BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800) AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
GROUP BY `mod_id`
ORDER BY m DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause is wrong, `WHERE (created - 604800)` will always be evaluated as `TRUE` unless `created` is null, it's basically the same as `WHERE 1`

```
SELECT `mod_id`, COUNT(`mod_id`) m 
from `history_spottings`
WHERE `created` >=  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800
GROUP BY `mod_id`
ORDER BY m DESC;
```